# controlling raster plot legend labels to display specified breaks value in r

Tags: r, break, legend, label, raster

I would like to hide some breaks value in the legend labels only displaying some specified value like min value or maxvalue.

```
library(raster)
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r1[] <- runif(ncell(r1))
n<-10
brks<-seq(minValue(r1),maxValue(r1),0.05)
plot(r1,breaks=brks,col=gray(seq(0,1,length=n)) )
```

The length of brks is 20, but I want to hide some values of brks in the legend labels and keep colors divided  by brks.

Questions:

1. How to display minvalue and maxvalue and hide the other value ?(same as strech render in arcmap )
2. How to display some specified value ?
   Pls make sure the brks is still working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plot method for `raster` objects takes an argument `axis.args` which gives you some control over the color table's annotation.

With your data, do something like this (and for more see the "Example" section of the help page returned by `help("plot", package="raster")`:

```
## Find the min and max z-values
rng <- range(r1[])

## Construct a list of arguments to be used for the color table
arg <- list(at=rng, labels=round(rng, 4))

## Pass them in to your call to plot
plot(r1,breaks=brks,col=gray(seq(0,1,length=n)), axis.args=arg)
```

[image]